# What is the difference between an algorithm, a language and a problem?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, formal-languages, terminology, reference-question

It seems that on this site, people will often correct others for confusing "algorithms" and "problems." What are the difference between these? How do I know when I should be considering algorithms and considering problems? And how do these relate to the concept of a language in formal language theory?

Comment: An algorithm is a way to solve a problem.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

For simplicity, I'll begin by only considering "decision" problems, which have a yes/no answer. Function problems work roughly the same way, except instead of yes/no, there is a specific output word associated with each input word.

**Language**: a language is simply a set of strings. If you have an alphabet, such as
$\Sigma$, then $\Sigma^*$ is the set of all words containing only the symbols in $\Sigma$.
For example, $\{0,1 \}^*$ is the set of all binary sequences of any length.
An alphabet doesn't need to be binary, though. It can be unary, ternary, etc.

A language over an alphabet $\Sigma$ is any subset of $\Sigma^*$.

**Problem**: A problem is some question about some input we'd like answered. Specifically, a decision problem is a question which asks, "Does our given input fulfill property $X$?

A language is the formal realization of a problem. When we want to reason theoretically about a decision problem, we often examine the corresponding language.
For a decision problem $X$, the corresponding language is:

> $L = \{w \mid w$ is the encoding of an input $y$ to problem $X$,
> and the answer to input $y$ for problem $X$ is "Yes"  $ \}$

Determining if the answer for an input to a decision problem is "yes" is equivalent to determining whether an encoding of that input over an alphabet is in the corresponding language.

**Algorithm**: An algorithm is a step-by-step way to solve a problem. Note that there an algorithm can be expressed in many ways and many languages, and that there are many different algorithms solving any given problem.

**Turing Machine**: A Turing Machine is the formal analogue of an algorithm. A Turing Machine over a given alphabet, for each word, either will or won't halt in an accepting state. Thus for each Turing Machine $M$, there is a corresponding language:

> $L(M) = \{w \mid M$ halts in an accepting state on input $w\}$.

(There's a subtle difference between Turing Machines that halt on all inputs and halt on yes inputs, which defines the difference between complexity classes $\mathsf{R}$ and $\mathsf{RE}$.)

The relationship between languages and Turing Machines is as follows

1. Every Turing Machine accepts exactly one language
2. There may be more than one Turing Machine that accept a given language
3. There may be no Turing Machine that accepts a given language.

We can say roughly the same thing about algorithms and problems: every algorithm solves a single problem, but there may be 0, or many, algorithms solving a given problem.

**Time Complexity**: One of the most common sources of confusion between algorithms and problems is in regards to complexity classes. The correct allocation can be summarized as follows:

- An algorithm *has* a time complexity
- A problem *belongs* to a complexity class

An algorithm can have a certain time complexity. We say an algorithm has a worst-case upper-bounded complexity
$f(n)$ if the algorithm halts in at most $f(n)$ steps for any input of size $n$.

Problems don't have run-times, since a problem isn't tied to a specific algorithm which actually runs. Instead, we say that a problem belongs to a complexity class, if there exists *some* algorithm solving that problem with a given time complexity.

$\mathsf{P}, \mathsf{NP}, \mathsf{PSPACE}, \mathsf{EXPTIME}$ etc. are all complexity classes. This means they contain problems, not algorithms. An algorithm can never be in $\mathsf{P}$, but if there's a polynomial-time algorithm solving a given problem $X$, then $X$ can be classified in complexity class $\mathsf{P}$. There could also be a bunch of other algorithms runs in different time complexity will also be able to solve the problem with the same input size under different time complexity, i.e. exponential-time algorithms, but since there already exists a single polynomial-time algorithm accepting $X$, it is in $\mathsf{P}$.

Comment: Please feel free to edit this answer as you see fit.

Comment: I think it would be good to mention that there are other kinds of computational problems (e.g. search problems).

Comment: A language can be infinite but an algorithm **MUST** halt in a finite number of steps.

Comment: Says who? That kind of thinking is part of why people had so much trouble formalizing and algorithm before the intention of the Turing Machine. The Church-Turing Thesis says that an algorithm IS a turing machine and vice versa, and not all turing machines halt.

Comment: Dude, this is the greatest answer I've ever seen.  You just summarized all of computer science in 1 page.

Comment: Thanks @CaptainCodeman! Though I did set myself up for it by asking it as a reference question :P

Comment: NP isn't really about the time complexity of solving a problem; it says (roughly) that a solution can be verified in polynomial time. NP and co-NP are very different, but take exactly the same time to solve.

Comment: @gnasher729 there's a theorem that says it can be defined in terms of verifying, but it's actual definition is in terms of time complexity for Non deterministic machines, thus the name NP: nondeterministic polynomial

Comment: @jmite Thank you for your answer. I also want to add that instead of saying "if there exists some algorithm solving that problem with a given time complexity" we say "if there exists at least one algorithm solving that problem with a given time complexity". Because for example it is enough to show one polynomial algorithm for solving a decision NP-complete problem to be in P.

Comment: @jmite Also, another note: instead of saying "... all complexity classes. [...] contain problems, not algorithms", we should say " ... all complexity classes. [...] contain languages". So, complexity class has a language [not algorithms and not problems]. The reason behind this is that x the input of the algorithm is subset of the alphabet. So, if $x \in P$, (where x is input and P is the problem) since x is input so it is subset from the alphabet. But P has no meaning here! there is a definition of problem. We have definition of problem in optimization that says:  ....

Comment: a problem is given some inputs with description and properties how to answer it. Now if we say $x \in L$, (where x is the input and L is the language that has special encoding of the problem) then we say the definition is fine.
Suppose that we do not know about x and we want to know whether it is a subset of this language or not. Then we use "algorithm" to see. Suppose Algorithm A is able to test whether x is subset of L or not. Then, we are able to say: If A[x] accepts, then $x \in L$ and if A[x] rejects, then $x \notin L$.

Answer (score 0):

Even more TLDR:

Problem: Given an input return an output related to the input in some way. Decision problems answer yes/no questions related to the input
Optimization problems seek to minimize or maximize some property related to the input.
Algorithm: a specific instance of solving a problem. Problems may have many algorithms that solve the problem
Language: formalization of the problem (in decision format). That is, the set of all strings spelled from an alphabet for which the problem is true (in the case of a decision problem).

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Append two blanks to lines you want a break after, e.g. `Algorithm:  `