# Relationship between functions and formal languages?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

PR is defined as "the complexity class of all primitive recursive functions"
and also equivalently as "the set of all formal languages that can be decided by such a function". (wiki:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PR_(complexity))

Unfortunately I fail to understand, why these two are equivalent?

Comment: Probably completey answered by [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13669/what-is-the-difference-between-an-algorithm-a-language-and-a-problem) -- community votes?

Comment: As far as I understand, the latter is a set of _decision_ problems, while the former consists of _function_ problems?