# What is the underlying structure of problems?

Tags: mathematical-foundations

We all the time write and talk about mathematical problems in plain English. For example, we define "the traveling salesman problem". But what is the actual, underlying structure of a "mathematical problem"? Can arbitrary mathematical problems be expressed exactly, in a formal language? Is it meaningful to talk about an algorithm that solves any arbitrary problem? Of course, that wouldn't decidable, but can we *express* it? For example, can we write a program which accepts, as input, a problem (example: *"find an algorithm that sorts a list optimally"*) and outputs a solution (example: *the merge sort algorithm*)?

Comment: I'm not sure that the term "problem" has a clear, precise, & standardly-accepted definition.  Take a look at http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/13669/755 for some explanation of standard usage of that term.

Comment: Are you looking for a formalization of mathematics as a language?