# Complexity of the algorithm to find occurences of a given number in a given array

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I have an algorithm that I think its complexity is O(n^2). However, our teacher insists that the algorithm takes O(n) time. How can it be? Here is the pseudo-code of the algorithm:

```
// A is the input array.
// |A| is the size of the input array.
i = 1
j = 1
m = 0
c = 0
while i < |A| {
    if A[i] == A[j] 
        c = c + 1
    j = j + 1

    if j > |A|
        if c > m
            m = c
        c = 0
        i = i + 1
        j = i
}
return m
```

Comment: Does your teacher claim this particular algorithm is O(n) (I agree with you that it is O(n^2), not O(n)), or that the problem _can_ be solved in O(n) (if so, please clarify what problem exactly you are trying to solve).

Comment: @user53923 He claims that this algorithm is O(n). I don't get it too. He is a little bit novice I think because he has a lot of mistakes when teaching stuff.

Comment: (Unless I misread something) the algorithm loops through all combinations of $i$ and $j$ with $i \leq j$ (and $i$ and $j$ between $1$ and $|A|$), resulting in $O(n^2)$

Comment: @hopingGI_in_P Please look at the comment of user53923. Because my solution is the same.

Comment: This algorithm, which indeed runs in time $\Theta(n^2)$, finds the number of occurrences of the most frequent element.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment, so post it here. This algorithm is definitely O(n^2). But if at each iteration you remove the elements already counted, it will become O(n) in BEST case. Also, if all the distinct elements are repeated k times equally, it becomes O(n log_k n). At the end, the worst case remains O(n^2) and that is counted as asymptotic analysis. The proof is using contradiction. When the input is list of n distinct elements, it has to iterate n(n+1)/2=O(n^2)

Comment: What, *exactly* is it that you want the algorithm to do? Because right now, it doesn't do what you claim it does. For one: where's the second input? What you claim it does can indeed be done in O(n), and is much simpler than this algorithm.

Comment: Please clarify: 1) What is the exact problem you are supposed to solve? 2) What is the exact statement your prof made? Where they talking about the problem, *some* algorithm, or this exact algorithm? (My guess: The professor said the problem could be solved in linear time, which the OP took to understand as that their algorithm ran in linear time. [Misintuitioned](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13669/what-is-the-difference-between-an-algorithm-a-language-and-a-problem).)

Answer (score 1):

If we retain only the references to `i` and `j`, the code reduces to

```
i = 1
j = 1
while i < |A| 
    j = j + 1
    if j > |A|
        i = i + 1
        j = i
```

This is equivalent to

```
for i in [1 |A|]
    for j in [i |A|]
```

... which is gone through about ${|A|^2 \over 2}$ times. So it is $\Theta(n^2)$: both $O(n^2)$ and $\Omega(n^2)$.

The algorithm appears to be looking for the maximum number of replicates in the array. There are faster ways to do so. A good hash map has (average) constant time access/update. So you can count how many of each thing are in the array in $\Theta(n)$ time. You can then find the maximum in $\Theta(n)$ time too.

So the problem admits a $\Theta(n)$ solution, but what you have been offered isn't it.

Comment: You'll need to show an $\Omega(n^2)$ bound as well.

Comment: @Raphael I've shown $\Omega$ as much as $O$, but I need to state it. Quite right. Thank you. I slipped into the false habit of using $O$ to express *of the order of*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the heading of your question :

> Complexity of the algorithm to find occurences of **a given number** in a
>   given array

Your algorithm finds multiple occurrences of ***all elements*** of the given array within itself which takes $O(n^2)$ time because $n$ elements are to be compared and each element needs $n-1$ comparisons.

But finding the multiple occurrences of **a** **given** **number** in an array will take only $O(n)$ time as we will have to compare only $1$ given number with $n$ elements of the given array i.e. $n$ times.

I guess you are talking about the complexity of **your algorithm**(which does more work than needed) but the teacher is telling you about the complexity of going through the array and **comparing each number in the array** with **the given number**.